# ASP.Net-Core - What methods can I use to create and store web articles?

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, asp.net-core, database-design

I have seen many tech websites that have their own web articles. What methods can I use to create and store these articles in a database? All while keeping structure such as paragraphs and placement of pictures. Also doing this using ASP.net Core and SQL Server.

Or should I not be storing them in a database but instead creating a web page for each web article?

Comment: You're asking about creating a Content Management System or more specifically a [Web Content Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system). There are myriad ways to structure and store this data, and each system does it differently. What you've asked is a very broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just store your articles' content in database.

Here's a series of articles about coding your own blog using ASP.NET Core:

[1 part](https://www.arctek.dev/blog/blog-with-csharp-pt1) - Introduction, **basics** and about models

[2 part](https://www.arctek.dev/blog/blog-with-csharp-pt2) - About controllers and views

[3 part](https://www.arctek.dev/blog/blog-with-csharp-pt3) - About using database (LiteDB, but sql server is also fits)

[4 part](https://www.arctek.dev/blog/blog-with-csharp-pt4) - **Markdown**. I guess that interests you more than other

[5 part](https://www.arctek.dev/blog/blog-with-csharp-pt5) - Admin panel

Good luck!